# Mudar valor de coluna no Firebird

Tags: sql, firebird

Tenho uma tabela com aproximadamente 7 mil registros, preciso criar uma nova coluna nessa tabela mas gostaria que todos os registros antigos ficassem com o valor 'S', quando tento criar a coluna os campos ficam com valor null mesmo passando como default 'S'. Como posso fazer essa alteração na minha tabela ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aós incluir a sua coluna, você pode dar um *update* na sua tabela para os casos em que o seu campo seja *null*.

```
update tabela
set campo = 'S'
where campo is null
```

Comment: Verdade, mas por precaução sempre faço todos os meus updates com where, então se tornou hábito colocar where sempre.